# In an existing free Google Apps account is there a way to determine the user limit?

Tags: limit, google-apps

I have a few Google Apps accounts created over the years for different domains. I understand the user limit is different depending on when the account was created. I can't find the limit mentioned anywhere in the dashboard though. Does anybody know a way of determining what the limit is?

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-settings/)

[GAM](http://ditoweb.com/dito-gam) can do this with:

[gam info domain](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/DomainSettingsExamples#Retrieving_Domain_Settings)

Comment: Very cool - but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. After granting GAM access from my computer and running python gam.py info domain from my Mac terminal I get an error:Domain cannot use API.

Comment: Did you turn on provisioning API? I'm able to use "gam info domain" on my Standard Edition domain (though not all gam commands work). http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60757

Comment: I just did that. But before I tried revoking the token thinking I could start all over and authorize it again. But I just get a Token revoked error now and no chance to restart. By the by, I never get email notifications from stackoverflow. Somebody recently said I need to favorite the discussion, but that didn't help. Anyway, I wonder if there is a way I can start over and set a scope for GAM. Thanks.

Comment: delete the oauth.txt file that is in the same directory as GAM. Then GAM should ask you to re-auth.

Comment: Well cool. It worked and reported that my domain is one of those with a maximum of 50 users. Great! Thanks! For security should I revoke the token or something, or can I leave it like that? Appreciate the help!

Comment: If your done with GAM, you can revoke the token but if you want to use it again and your computer is secured (physical and virtual) where no unauthorized users could grab the oauth.txt, you should be fine.